# New instance of singleton with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have pretty big instance of singleton created through Dagger 2. But I need to drop that instance and create brand new and clean. How can I do it with Dagger 2?

Comment: Create a singleton holder class and replace it in that

Comment: I have done exactly what @EpicPandaForce has done. Works well. Alternatively, depending on your use case, you could recreate your root component and that would force ALL your instances to refresh.